# NVIDIA-SMI has failed because it couldn't communicate with the NVIDIA driver. Make sure that the latest NVIDIA driver is installed and running. Why?

Tags: tensorflow, gpu, google-colaboratory, nvidia

I'm trying to run stylegan2 on Google Colab but with all the files on my Drive and avoiding using !git clone from the [github of stylegan2](https://github.com/pbaylies/stylegan2).
Here is my code on the specific cell:

```
    %tensorflow_version 1.x
    %cd /content/drive/My Drive/stylegan2-master/
    !nvcc test_nvcc.cu -o test_nvcc -run
    print('Tensorflow version: {}'.format(tf.__version__) )
    !nvidia-smi -L
    print('GPU Identified at: {}'.format(tf.test.gpu_device_name()))
```

And the result:

/content/drive/My Drive/stylegan2-master
CPU says hello.
cudaErrorNoDevice: no CUDA-capable device is detected
Tensorflow version: 1.15.2
**NVIDIA-SMI has failed because it couldn't communicate with the NVIDIA driver. Make sure that the latest NVIDIA driver is installed and running.**

GPU Identified at:

Why can't I get the GPU ?
I am new in the field so I may be missing something very simple, but still can't find out on the internet the answer.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You have to enable the GPU first in the Notebook settings.

You can easily do it by clicking on `Edit > Notebook settings` and selecting GPU as hardware accelerator.

That should be it.

Comment: Sorry, I completely misunderstood your answer

Comment: In my case, I have done this in multiple notebooks and am still not being issued a GPU or TPU, even after restarting the runtime.